# prime case function?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Does there exist a *name* (or assigned to a mathemtician) for a *case function* $f(x)$ in literature, such that it twould take the value $1$ when $x$ primes, and zero otherwise?

I am just looking for a reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is only named as "characteristic function of primes"

As far as I know it does not have a name